# What is the complexity of computing $C(n + m, m)$?

Tags: time-complexity

$C$ here represents combinations.
$$
C(n + m, m) =  \frac{(n + m)!}{n! m!} = \frac{(n + m) * (n + m - 1) * \ldots * (n + 1)}{m!}
$$

In this formula it looks like it's $O(m)$ because both the numerator and denominator is $O(m)$, if I'm not mistaken.

Alternatively,
$$
C(n + m, m) =  \frac{(n + m)!}{n! m!} = \frac{(n + m) * (n + m - 1) * \ldots * (m + 1)}{n!}
$$
In this formula it looks like it's $O(n)$ because both the numerator and denominator is $O(n)$, if I'm not mistaken.

So is the complexity $O(\min(n, m))$?

Comment: It depends on how you compute it. If you compute it using the first formula, then its $O(m)$ assuming multiplication and division take $O(1)$. If you compute using the second formula then its $O(n)$. And if you want something in $O(min(n,m))$ then check whether $n<m$ or vice versa and use that knowledge to compute using the faster formula. Again, this is assuming multiplication and division take $O(1)$, which isn't realistic for "big integers" as @Pseudonym stated.

Answer (score 3):

In the word RAM model, any pure function which takes a constant number of machine words and returns a constant number of machine words is assumed to cost $O(1)$ time. This is because any such function could, in principle, be implemented as a static memory lookup or a new CPU instruction.

If you're asking about the complexity of a specific algorithm, then analyse the algorithm, not the problem.

If you're asking about the case where $m$ or $n$ are *not* representable as a constant number of words (i.e. "big integers"), then neither algorithm that you presented is optimal for sufficiently large $m+n$. Remember that multiplication and division of large integers are not $O(1)$-time operations!